# what is ascii 7-bit character set and ascii 8-bit character set?

Tags: ascii

Im new to this, so ascii 7 bit can represent 128 values, then ascii 8 can represent 256 values? this right?
ascii 7-bit character set: 01000001 represents ‘A’
how would a look like in ascii 8 bit? or any other example of 8-bit character set?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII is seven bits, per the standard. Anything done with an eighth bit is unrelated to ASCII, and should be called something not-ASCII (e.g. UTF-8). Alas, folks invented all manner of complications termed "extended ascii" but this only confuses the fact that ASCII is seven bits. As to the bit patterns, computers are fairly good at computing that:

```
$ perl -e 'printf "%07b\n%08b\n", map { ord } qw/A A/' 
1000001
01000001
```